# How do i find the similar rows depending on column values in SQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am building an e commerce pc store and have stored all the products with their specifications as columns (so RAM, processor, colour, brand etc are all different columns)
I have built a search to find the products and linked it to a page where people can view the product and all the info about it 
When someone views a product i would like a section for "similar products". 
It should get these products based on the values of the different columns and get the BEST matches

for example say i have the products table here:

```
+----+------+--------+-------+--------+--------+
| id | Name |  Type  | Brand | Colour | Memory |
+----+------+--------+-------+--------+--------+
| 1  | Name1| laptop |  Asus | White  |  2GB   |
| 2  | Name2| laptop |  Acer |  Red   |  4GB   | 
| 3  | Name3|computer|   Hp  |  Blue  |  3GB   | 
| 4  | Name4| laptop |  Acer |  White |  6GB   | 
| 5  | Name5| laptop |   HP  |  Red   |  4GB   | 
+----+------+--------+-------+--------+--------+
```

Lets say that the user was viewing product id 1
then in order, the best matches would be:

```
+----+------+--------+-------+--------+--------+
| id | Name |  Type  | Brand | Colour | Memory |
+----+------+--------+-------+--------+--------+
| 4  | Name4| laptop |  Acer | White  |  6GB   |
| 2  | Name2| laptop |  Acer |  Red   |  4GB   | 
| 5  | Name5| laptop |   Hp  |  Red   |  4GB   | 
| 3  | Name3|computer|   HP  |  Blue  |  3GB   | 
+----+------+--------+-------+--------+--------+
```

so i guess, in a nutshell what i am asking is, how would i select all the rows with the most matching columns, in order of how many matching columns it has with the current row

Comment: exactly how does `productid 1` relate to this table, other than apparently having id=1 means you DON'T want "id=1" in the results?

Comment: No i dont since they are viewing product id 1, it wouldnt make sense to have product id 1 shown in the similar products section

Comment: based on your requirement of getting `similar products`, it shouldn't be done in the database comparing the columns. You should use similarity scores (assigning ordinal values to each column based on requirements and treating the whole row as a set) or distance based measures (Manhattan distance for example) to determine similar groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the number of identical columns between the item of interest and the set of remaining items and sort by the sum of number of matches.

If you want to give priority to some attribute you can alter the arithmetic to include weights. So for example the boolean expression `t1.Memory = t2.Memory` which evaluates to 1 or 0 could be changed to use to the absolute value of the difference in memory to get the closest match. Et cetera.

Note that this query uses fixed attributes and assumes no null values - if there can be nulls you need to handle that (using coalesce for example) and you could also use dynamic sql to account for a varying number of attributes to compare.

Also, not all databases can evaluate boolean expressions like `t1.Memory = t2.Memory` (MySQL can) and it is really a short form for `case when t1.Memory = t2.Memory then 1 else 0 end`

```
select 
    t1.*
    , sum(t1.type = t2.type) 
    + sum(t1.Brand = t2.Brand) 
    + sum(t1.Colour = t2.Colour)  
    + sum(t1.Memory = t2.Memory) as commonality
from products  t1, products  t2 
where t2.id = 1 and t1.id <> t2.id
group by t1.id, t1.Name, t1.Type, t1.Brand, t1.Colour, t1.Memory
order by 
  sum(t1.type = t2.type) 
  + sum(t1.Brand = t2.Brand) 
  + sum(t1.Colour = t2.Colour) 
  + sum(t1.Memory = t2.Memory) desc, Brand
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a41c9/1)

With your sample data and ID 1 as the item to compare with the result would be:

```
| id |  Name |     Type | Brand | Colour | Memory | commonality |
|----|-------|----------|-------|--------|--------|-------------|
|  4 | Name4 |   laptop |  Acer |  White |    6GB |           2 |
|  2 | Name2 |   laptop |  Acer |    Red |    4GB |           1 |
|  5 | Name5 |   laptop |    HP |    Red |    4GB |           1 |
|  3 | Name3 | computer |    Hp |   Blue |    3GB |           0 |
```

Comment: Good Answer... It's also worth noting that you can use a factor to multiply each of the summed values to assign a weight to particular match types. Like if you valued Type matches to be twice that of the other factors you could do `sum(t1.type = t2.type) * 2`

Comment: @Orangepill Indeed, it would be simple to include weights (or even let the user determine priority order)